# I am getting an Index Error in the following code and i am very confused as to why

Tags: python, index-error

In the following code its showing me to have an index error. I am very confused as to where the mistake is.

```
the_list = [[0] * i for i in range(10)]
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        the_list[i][j] = i * j
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        print(the_list[i][j], end=", ")
    print()
```

Comment: It depends on what you want the code to do. Do you want a square or triangle matrix in `the_list`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a triangular list-of-lists, but the indexing patterns that follow suggest you want a square list-of-lists.  If that's the case, change:

```
the_list = [[0] * i for i in range(10)]
```

to:

```
the_list = [[0] * 10 for i in range(10)]
```

On the other hand, if you really intended to create a triangular list-of-lists, then instead of changing the list creation, you would need to change the indexing patterns that follow from:

```
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
```

to:

```
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(i):
```

Comment: How do you know what the OP wants?

Comment: So how do you know this is so and not that `the_list` is correct and the patterns that follow are wrong.

Comment: @quamrana Ok, I updated my answer to address both possibilities.

Comment: Ok, excellent. I put it to you that you made a mistake, acknowledged your mistake and corrected your mistake. Well done! +1.

Comment: @quamrana Thanks.  It's not always easy to understand what someone's intent is.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I was (and still am) waiting for the OP to respond.